# Research has shown that vegetarians tend to live longer than meateaters - what about vegans?

Tags: health

[Research has indicated](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/vegetarians-live-longer-longevity_n_1961967?utm_hp_ref=healthy-living) that vegetarians live on average 9.5 years longer than meateaters (if male) and 6.1 years longer (if female), giving an overall average of about 8 years longer. That is [similar](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/plant-based-diet_b_1981838) to the gap between non-smokers and smokers.

Clearly other factors apart from diet are also involved. For example, the referenced research found that vegetarians are on average 14kg (30lb, or 2 stones and 2 pounds) lighter than meateaters. And diets vary among vegetarians, as they also vary among meateaters. Nonetheless, that is still very interesting research.

My question is this:

**has there been any similar research on veganism?**

For example, has there been a study comparing vegans with non-vegan vegetarians for life expectancy, or for that matter vegans with meateaters?

Comment: Peripheral to your question really but I want to mention that the context of the study you mentioned is important - all of its subjects are Californians. In other areas, vegetarians may not have better life expectancy than non-vegetarians

Comment: There are many factors that influence life expectancy and the issue is very complex. 
I don't think there's any comprehensive study out there comparing vegans and vegetarians when it comes to life expectancy. Perhaps there are only individual studies on various factors/causes of illnesses/pre-mature deaths among people.

Comment: There are studies such as [this](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2540540).

Answer (score 1):

There is some data available from a study on Seventh Day Adventists by [Orlich et al](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23836264/). The sample size was 73,308.

The rates for all-cause mortality were as follows (lower is better, where 1 is a standard omnivorous diet):

- All vegetarians 0.88
- Vegans 0.85
- Lacto-ovo vegetarians 0.91
- Pescatarians 0.81
- Semi-vegetarians 0.92

It should be noted there there are other studies such as [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10479225/) and [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26657045/) which, whilst they don't look specifically at vegans, give slightly less flattering results for vegetarians when it comes to all-cause mortality - although the risk for specific diseases was lower.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Those are hazard ratios. I wonder whether there is a way to pull out a Q&D estimate of a life expectancy differential using those figures and some reasonable assumptions. If we were utterly Q&D we could go from 0.88 -> (9.5y,6.1y;7.8y)  to 0.85 -> (0.15/0.12)*(9.5y,6.1y;7.8y) =(11.9y,7.6y;9.8y).